# Github how to rewrite local code with online code

Tags: github

I edited my code in a different computer and uploaded it to github. Now i want to download or update my local code in another different computer. If i press revert it tells me

Cannot revert the commit because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before reverting the commit again

and if i press pull it tells me

An error occurred. Detailed message: 6 uncommitted changes would be overwritten by merge

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXIbh.png)

Help with pictures please. I tried all the buttons available. Push pull commit fetch revert. I still get errors and cant download my code. I dunno what all the buttons are for. I only know how to commit and sync. No command line please help thanks.

Comment: you can use git commit -a while git pull

Comment: I am using visual studio. I do not know how to commit -a git pull. Pictures please

Answer (score 0):

You need to `git stash` or discard your local changes before you can pull from your remote.

Answer (score 0):

if you configure git in path.open CMD and go to  project source path.
then enter `git stash` it will discard all commits which your did earlier.
then use `git pull`. If there are any conflicts occur use `git commit -a`.
it will merge your local code and remote source code.